# Firefox Web-Extension with Javascript doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wrote a quite simple FFox Extension which works on my Office-PC (win10) but does not on my Home PC (win11). Same for my colleague. The extension calls a javascript which logs every step in the console, but on my home-PC the script is not shown in the "Debugger" and the console log stays empty, so I don't know what is happening and where to start.

- the Extension adds a right-click-context-menu-item
- when you click this (which is also available at my home PC) a script gets executed

Here's the code of the script

```
/*
Called when the item has been created, or when creation failed due to an error.
We'll just log success/failure here.
*/
function onCreated() {
  if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log(`Error: ${browser.runtime.lastError}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Item created successfully");
  }
}

/*
Called when the item has been removed.
We'll just log success here.
*/
function onRemoved() {
  console.log("Item removed successfully");
}

/*
Called when there was an error.
We'll just log the error here.
*/
function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

/*
Create all the context menu items.
*/
chrome.menus.create({
  id: "log-selection",
  title: browser.i18n.getMessage("menuItemSelectionLogger"),
  contexts: ["selection"]
}, onCreated);

/*
The click event listener, where we perform the appropriate action given the
ID of the menu item that was clicked.
*/
chrome.menus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  switch (info.menuItemId) {
    case "log-selection":
      browser.tabs.executeScript({
        code: `console.log('Start fetching...');fetch('https://CUSTOMIPADRESS/${info.selectionText}').then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('fetch failed:'+error);alert('fetch failed (try visit
https://CUSTOMIPADRESS and manually allow certificate):'+error);
    });`
      });
      break;
  }
});
```

As soon as I start it from the context menu in my Office-Browser I can see the script in the FFOX-Debugger, can debug into it etc.. When I do the same on my Home-PC nothing shows up. I can visit the CUSTOMIPADRESS manually and get results. I also deactivated my firewall for testing purposes.

Any idea what happens here and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
If you go to extension you can enter a debug mode for this add-on and there you can see an error log with more detail. In my case it was this line

```
   console.log('fetch failed:'+error);alert('fetch failed (try visit
https://CUSTOMIPADRESS and manually allow certificate):'+error);
```

needs to be in one line because the ' doesnt close when a newline is entered.